# Livewire choicesjs component with AplineJS returns Cannot redefine property: $nextTick

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I try to get working  choicesjs with livewire but I get on the way a lot problems. For now what I try

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class ChoicesLivewire extends Component
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public array $options;


    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public array $selectedOptions;


    protected $listeners = [
        'reloaded'
    ];

    public function mount()
    {
        $collection = [
            1 => 'Architektur',
            2 => 'Bauwirtschaft',
            3 => 'Straßenbau',
            4 => 'Tiefbau',
        ];

        $this->options = $collection;
        $this->selectedOptions = [2];
    }

    public function updatedOptions()
    {
        //dump($this->selectedOptions);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('reloaded', ['currentSelects' => $this->selectedOptions]);
        return view('livewire.choices-livewire');
    }
}
```

than the blade

```
<div>
    <select wire:model="options" x-ref="multiple" x-data="livewareChoices"  multiple>
        @foreach($options as $key => $option)
            <option value="{{$key}}" {{ in_array($key, $selectedOptions) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$option}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    @dump($selectedOptions)
</div>
```

and my custom js file

```
import Choices from "choices.js";

window.choices = Choices;

const livewareChoices = {
    init() {
        if (!typeof Choices === 'function' || !this.$refs.multiple) return;

        const self = this
        //console.log(this.$wire.livewareChoices)
        choices = new Choices(this.$refs.multiple, {
            itemSelectText: '',
            removeItems: true,
            //allowHTML: true,
            removeItemButton: true,
        });

        /*choices.passedElement.element.addEventListener(
            'change',
            function (event) {
                console.log(self.$refs.$attributes)
                //self.$wire.set('livewareChoices', event.target.value)
            })*/
    }
}
window.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
    window.livewareChoices = livewareChoices;
})
```

on request choices is getting rendered correctly as I try to select some values choicesjs will break with the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $nextTick`. What is wrong in this case?